# Check if record exists in database with resultset

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I want to check if an int value exists in my database. I have 2 classes, one class where I make the jdbc connection (the method is called "checkid"):

```
Statement stmt = null;
String query = SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE id = ?";
try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    if (rs != null){
    System.out.println("result set has got something"); 
    while (rs.next())
    { 
        //NOW YOU'RE ON ROW 1
    }
} else {
    out.println("result set is empty");  
} catch (SQLException e ) {
    JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
}
```

And a class where i call this method and now my question is. How can i check if the record exists?
I think it is something like this:

```
int id = 10; 
JDBCClass jdbcClass = new JDBCClass ();
if (jdbcClass.checkid(id) == null)
    System.err.println("null");
```

Comment: I would replace the placeholder "?" in your sql...

Comment: If you are only checking that the record exists then you can try to use `select 1` instead of `select *` Also the syntax is presently wrong, it should be `select * from table1`(*you are missing the **from***)

Comment: Your method should probably return `boolean` unless the value is of any use, then you could simply do `select count(*) from Table1 where id = ?` and you just need to return `rs.getLong(1) > 0`

Comment: But how can I check the result of this resultset in the other class?

Comment: @MeesvanZ, so you want `rs` from here to other class to process the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this. `isBeforeFirst()` will return true if the cursor is before the first row;

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
if(!rs.isBeforeFirst()){
    System.out.println("result set is empty");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Result set is not empty");
}
```

For sake of completeness, you should probably alter the method to return a boolean and use a prepared statement, it's a good habbit to get into for the future. Something like this would probably be the best solution.

```
public boolean checkId(int id) {
    String sql = "Select 1 from MyTable where id = ?";  

    PreparedStatement ps = dbConn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, id);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    return rs.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In first class,

```
public ResultSet checkId(int id) {
    String sql = "Your query";  

    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, id);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    return rs;//return result rs here
}
```

In other class simply,

```
ResultSet rs = jdbcClass.checkid(id);
if (rs == null)
    System.err.println("null");
else
{
 //process the result rs here since record id exists
 while(rs.next())
 {
   //some...
 }
}
```